# PowerShell How to determine script execution?

Tags: powershell

I was wondering how it's possible to determine if a PowerShell script has been launched from within the Windows PowerShell ISE by clicking Play, or if it has been launched by a scheduled task or something else?

By searching I found the variable `$MyInvocation.CommandOrigin`, is this something that could to the trick? Thank you for your advice.

I also found the following from [here](http://poshoholic.com/2008/03/18/powershell-deep-dive-using-myinvocation-and-invoke-expression-to-support-dot-sourcing-and-direct-invocation-in-shared-powershell-scripts/) but it's not really determining if it's executed in the ISE or not:

```
if ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq ‘&‘) {
    “Called using operator“
} elseif ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq ‘.‘) {
    “Dot sourced“
} elseif ((Resolve-Path -Path ` 
    $MyInvocation.InvocationName).ProviderPath -eq `
    $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) {
    “Called using path $($MyInvocation.InvocationName)“
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the presence of the $PSISE variable. It is only present in ISE and is $null or undefined in the console.

```
#In the console this will output False
#In the ISE this will output True
if($PSISE){$true}else{$false}
```

Comment: From a Scheduled Task this will also output False I presume. Thank you :)